# encodeURIComponent doesn't give me the desired output

Tags: jquery, url, encoding, urlencode, encodeuricomponent

I'm creating an app which screen scrapes a site with the help of user input (street, city). However, a street or a city could have the characters 'å', 'ä' and 'ö', which needs to be encoded.

I've tried encodeURIComponent, but it doesn't output the same as the site I'm about to scrape when inputing street and city directly in the form on the page (se below). What can I use/do instead to get the desired output?

```
var url = 'http://www.foosite.com/result.jspv?street=' +
encodeURIComponent(street) + '&city=' + encodeURIComponent(city);

From my app:   http://www.foosite.com/result.jspv?street=Vaktarev%C3%A4gen&city=M%C3%B6nster%C3%A5s
From the site: http://www.foosite.com/result.jspv?street=Vaktarev%E4gen&city=M%F6nster%E5s
```

Comment: Maybe use `escape` instead of `encodeURIComponent`. The former gives the "from the site" result.

Comment: `encodeURIComponent` generates UTF-8 values; the site you're using uses the Unicode code point, which is generated using `escape`. See the code point `U+00E4` on http://www.utf8-chartable.de/ for an example with `ä`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The site is probably using `escape`, which returns a Unicode code point. In contrast, `encodeURIComponent` generates a UTF-8 value. (Scroll down to the `U+00E4` code point on http://www.utf8-chartable.de/ for the differing values of `ä`.)

I would generally discourage use of the [`escape`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.escape) function, since it is not specified in any kind of standard. However, since this probably the easiest way to match the behavior of the site (which sadly does not use the preferred `encodeURIComponent`), it's certainly the best option for you here. Despite being nonstandard, it should work in virtually all browsers.